# How to solve could not find provisional profiles for bluetooth.xamarin.ios

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022, provisioning-profile, ios-bluetooth

I am building a solution on visual studio and I get an error that says” could not find any available provisioning profiles for xamarin.ios on IOS

I was able to set a provisional profile in .IOS file but in Bluetooth.xamarin.ios project on bundle signing it says no matching profiles

Comment: What key is added to this your `infoplist`? And what's added to `capabilities`? You can try to add a profile manually. For more information, please check document  [Working with Capabilities in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/?tabs=macos).